# Buttons and radiobuttons appear disabled when form is opened

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I dont understand one thing. I have form which opened if LicencePlate is bad. In this form i have few buttons, textboxes and radio buttons. These buttons and radio buttons are enabled and disabled based on conditions.

There is a piece of code for textbox LicencePlate, which will disable or enable these radio buttons and buttons.

```
// <summary>
    /// Fill Licence Plate with LicencePlateFinal from NotifiedTruck.
    /// </summary>
    public String LicencePlate
    {
        get { return PlateInformation.LicencePlateFinal; }
        set
        {
            PlateInformation.LicencePlateFinal = value;               

            // Musí volat domeček - pokud se avizovaná a skutečná liší.
            // Call house - if avizo  != LicencePlateNotified
            if (LicencePlate != Avizo)
            {
                _canEnableBtn = false;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableButton");
                _canEnableAcpt = true;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableAccept");
                _canEnableRadio = true;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableRadio");                  
            }

            // Avizovaná se rovná skutečné, ale liší se od OCRkované: povolují nakládku tlačítkem Pokračovat v nakládce která otevře detail vozidla v samostatném formuláři
            // Avizo == LicencePlateFinal , but Avizo != OCR  or LicencePlateFinal != OCR; then you can continue in loading process.
            else if (LicencePlate == Avizo || LicencePlate != PlateInformation.LicencePlateOCR || Avizo != PlateInformation.LicencePlateOCR)
            {
                _canEnableBtn = true;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableButton");
                _canEnableAcpt = false;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableAccept");
                _canEnableRadio = false;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableRadio");                   
            }
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LicencePlate");
        }
    }
```

When i open the form. All fields are disabled. When i click on LicencePlate TextBox and write some think, the conditions activate. But i want activate conditions when the form is opened. Not after i write some text inside LicencePlate textbox. I have also bind update source trigger at the specifics radio buttons and buttons.

Here is the property set:

```
public bool CanEnableButton
    {
        get
        {
            return _canEnableBtn;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_canEnableBtn != value)
            {
                _canEnableBtn = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableButton");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanEnableRadio
    {
        get 
        {              

            return _canEnableRadio;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_canEnableRadio != value)
            {
                _canEnableRadio = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableRadio");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanEnableAccept
    {
        get
        {
            return _canEnableAcpt;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_canEnableAcpt != value)
            {
                _canEnableAcpt = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableAccept");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here the xaml for radio buttons and buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="btnContinueLoading" IsEnabled="{Binding CanEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Command="{Binding ContinueLoadingCmd}"  Style="{StaticResource DialogButton}" Content="POKRAČOVAT V NÁKLADCE" Grid.Column="1" Height="31" Width="181" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,11,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    </Button>

    <RadioButton x:Name="chcxReturnState" Content="VRÁTIT" GroupName="Requests" IsChecked="{Binding IsReturned, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             IsEnabled="{Binding CanEnableRadio, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,22,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="61"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="chcxWaitState" Content="POČKAT" GroupName="Requests" IsChecked="{Binding IsWaiting, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
                             IsEnabled="{Binding CanEnableRadio, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,22,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="POTVRDIT" Command="{Binding ConfirmRequestCmd, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsEnabled="{Binding CanEnableAccept,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,14,0,0" Grid.Row="2"  Height="31" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181" Style="{StaticResource DialogButton}"/>
```

Any tips? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post all codes where this property is set

Comment: and also the code that actual disables the controls, in you question i see no code that enables/disables any controls

Comment: ok, i posted my code for xaml and the bool properties as well

Comment: My guess is that the control that is binded to LicensePlate has its value changed when opening the form because the bindingsource is opened. That will somehow change the property LicensePlate at a time when the control's value is still empty.

Comment: So delete the property changed from LicencePlate?

Comment: no not delete it. If this is confirmed to be the problem than you have 2 choises. 1) set the Changed property not in designer but in code after the bindingsource has opened. 2) keep the Changed property but add a flag that you set after opening the bindingsource, and in the Changed property check for this flag

Answer (score 1):

Insted of this

```
public bool CanEnableButton
{
    get
    {
        return _canEnableBtn;
    }

    set
    {
       _canEnableBtn = value;
       NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableButton");
    }
}

public bool CanEnableRadio
{
    get 
    {              

        return _canEnableRadio;
    }

    set
    {
        _canEnableRadio = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableRadio");
    }
}

public bool CanEnableAccept
{
    get
    {
        return _canEnableAcpt;
    }

    set
    {
         _canEnableAcpt = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("CanEnableAccept");
    }
```

In your constructor set the flags what ever you want.
This is will work.

Suppose let assume your constructor like this

```
public YourConstructor()
{
 CanEnableAccept=true;
 CanEnableRadio=true;
 CanEnableButton=true;
}
```

Comment: In constructor is ok. But i need this in conditions. This conditions are in string LicencePlate, which will enable the buttons and radios after the conditions are succcesful or not.

Comment: change the name of button '_canEnableAcpt' to 'CanEnableAccept' change all flags like this it s works

Comment: i did it, but no effect :/

Comment: hey are u using mvvm light or caliburn micro

Comment: no its company platform based on c# and mvvm pattern

Comment: hey, can you mail me that folder. i willcheck what's the problem(raghavaradical@gmail.com)